# Cannot call method appendChild of null

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table, appendchild

It occurs in this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<phoneNums.length; i++)
{
    var lines = document.createElement('tr');
    var number = document.createElement('td');
    number.innerHTML = phoneNums[i];
    var minutes = document.createElement('td');
    minutes.innerHTML = minutesUsed[i];
    var plan = document.createElement('td');
    plan.innerHTML = plans[i];
    var charges = document.createElement('td');
    charges.innerHTML = charge[i];
    document.getElementById('theTable').appendChild(lines);
    lines.appendChild(number);
    lines.appendChild(minutes);
    lines.appendChild(plan);
    lines.appendChild(charges);
}
```

---

Specifically at:

`document.getElementById('theTable').appendChild(lines);`

```
<table id = 'theTable'>
        </table>
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            populateTable();
        </script>
```

I'm trying to create a function that adds `tr` and `td` and the values to a table.

Comment: does the `theTable` html element exist in the document? And, are you executing this script after the page has finished loading?

Comment: theTable is the id for my table which everything is being added in and the script executes onload

Comment: try cut/pasting the script element to the end of the html, if it still doesn't work that means you've probably got a typo.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML part and the call for the above JS.

Comment: @Adi Please don't direct users to off-site tools like JSfiddle. The question needs to contain a complete example, and that cannot be a JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are running this script before "theTable" exists in your document. Make sure that this script occurs below your table with `id="theTable"`, or that it is run in an event handler that occurs after the table exists.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you do not have an element in your DOM with an id of "theTable". Somewhere in your html you should have something like:

```
<table id="theTable">...
```

Alternatively, as others have also mentioned, this element may not have been loaded into the DOM before your script executes.